# Why call the default destructor of an object before freeing the memory allocated to that object?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I seen some code do the following:

```
ExampleObject< T > * eo = const_cast< ExampleObject< T > * >(this);
eo->~ExampleObject();
free( eo );
```

The ExampleObject in question has been allocated using placement new.
There is no user-defined destructor supplied, so it's the compiler supplied default destructor being used here, I think.

I don't understand why it is necessary to call the destructor here. If we had a user-defined destructor that de-allocated memory for some of it's class members I could understand the usage here, but in the case of a default destructor I don't know why we'd do this.

**What does the default destructor of an object do, that would require us to call it before freeing the allocated memory for the object?**

Comment: the `dtor` is called when the object goes out of scope. you don't have to manually call any of these. and free is c not c++

Comment: It is appropriate if you used placement new to construct the object.

Comment: Don't wing the syntax in this question. It makes the question itself unclear. Very likely you saw: `exampleObject->~ClassName()`, where `ClassName` is the the class used to create `exampleObject`. You only see this if the memory was allocated using `malloc` instead of `new`, and was initialized with a placement `new`.

Comment: placement new was indeed used to construct the object, I'll edit the question to include this -- maybe you could write an answer explaining why?

Comment: Updated the code example for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does the default destructor of an object do

It calls the destructors, if any, for the object's data members.

> that would require us to call it before freeing the allocated memory for the object?

The ONLY time a destructor should ever be called *explicitly* is when the object has been constructed using [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) inside a pre-existing memory block.  Using `placement-new` separates the tasks of object construction/destruction from memory allocation/deallocation, so you need to construct and destruct an object explicitly, but you don't have to allocate/deallocate its memory block, you can manage that however you want elsewhere.

If you do not use `placement-new` to construct the object, but rather allocate + construct the object using `new` instead, then you must destruct + deallocate the object using `delete` (and you should preferably use a smart pointer, `std:unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, to handle that for you).

If you do not construct the object using any form of `new`, then DO NOT try to destruct the object manually at all.  The object is in *automatic storage* and the compiler will manage it for you.

Comment: you don't need to explicitly call dtor if you used new and delete.

Comment: @oblivion If you use the **non**-placement `new`, then yes. DO NOT use `delete` if you use `placement-new`

Answer (score 1):

The C allocation functions know nothing about C++ objects.  Unlike `new` and `delete` that allocate the memory needed and call the constructor/destructor, all The C functions do is allocate/deallocate a suitably sized amount of memory that you can use.

So when you use the C functions, you have to call the allocation function to get the memory, call placement new on it to actually construct the object in the memory (this is required to actually have an object of that type).  Then, when you are done with it you need to destroy the object by manually calling the destructor (you need to do this so the objects lifetime properly ends) and then pass the pointer to free so the memory can be released.

This is why you should not be using `*alloc` and `free` in C++.  They require a lot of extra work and are not type safe.

Answer (score 0):

A default destructor function is called automatically when the object goes out of scope:

1. The function ends
2. The program ends
3. A block containing local variables ends
4. A delete operator is called

Default destructor always invokes the destructors of its member objects (not for member variables that are pointers to objects). If we allocate memory dynamically it should be handled by us, otherwise default destructor clears the local variables.

If we do not write our own destructor in class, the compiler creates a default destructor for us. The default destructor works fine unless we have dynamically allocated memory or pointer in class. 
When a class contains a pointer to memory allocated in class, we should write a destructor to release memory before the class instance is destroyed. This must be done to avoid memory leak.